# Task ‘bintrayUpload’ not found in root project after update Android studio to 3.0

Tags: gradle, aar, bintray

Before I update gradle and android studio I used to upload my library to bintray with these tasks from this [tutorial](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en):

first: `gradlew install`

second: `gradlew bintrayUpload`

But after updating android studio and gradle I had to change fist task to: gradlew `installDebug`
but gradle can not find task`bintrayUpload` and I get this error:

```
* What went wrong:
Task 'bintrayUpload' not found in root project 'MyProject'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was here: I had to add these lines in lib gradle.

```
// Place it at the end of the file
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/installv1.gradle'
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/bintrayv1.gradle'
```

And it loads and adds bintray tasks to the gradle.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a `bintray` task in your `build.gradle`. Since you do not have one, `gradlew` cannot find and therefore execute that task. Define something like the following according to your settings and you will be fine.

```
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'


bintray {
    user = ...
    key = ....
    publications = ....
    pkg {
        ...
    }
}
```